# why am I getting "object Object" when I call .toString on a JS array?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to look at all the cookies in a given document with this:

```
function get_cookies_array() {
    var cookies = {};

    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var split = document.cookie.split(';');

        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            var name_value = split[i].split("=");
            name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
            cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
        }
    }

    return cookies;
}

var cookies = get_cookies_array();

alert(cookies.toString());
```

However, what i'm seeing in the alert box is

```
[object Object]
```

I was expecting a comma separated list of values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it is not an array.

Comment: "[object Object]" is the default [ToString] of "normal" objects..: `alert({})`.

Comment: can someone who downvoted me please explain what exactly is so bad about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value being returned is not an array. It's a plain object. Presumably you *do* want to use an object here, so that you can use string-valued keys. You can print out its contents like so:

```
var cookies = get_cookies_array();

console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies));
```

Or line by line:

```
Object.keys(cookies).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key, ' - ', cookies[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `var cookies = {};` with `var cookies = [];` so that you are dealing with an Array instead of an Object.

Then, because you are using an associative array, also change your writing into array like this:

```
cookies.push([decodeURIComponent(name_value[0]), decodeURIComponent(name_value[1])]);
```

Comment: Oh, I've missed that we are dealing with an associative array. I've updated my answer. It probably not ideal, but works without having to write your own `toString()` function.